# MuleSoft : How to write choice structure in RAML spec file?

Tags: xsd, mule, raml

How to write choice structure in RAML spec file ?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve here. I guess XSD is XML schemas. RAML and XSD have completely different objectives and formats. Please also provide some examples of the input and expected results.

Comment: The question has been changed but it is not yet clear. Please explain what is a choice structure, what is the intended usage, and what you tried. See Stackoverflow how to ask good questions guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask